# Evaluating the limit of $\frac{\ln\sin mx}{\ln \sin x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'd need some help evaluating this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln\sin mx}{\ln \sin x}$$

I know it's supposed to equal 1 but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Immediate aplication of L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We need $x>0$ and $m>0$ then by standard limits

$$\frac{\ln\sin mx}{\ln \sin x}=\frac{\ln\frac{\sin mx}{mx}+\ln (mx)}{\ln \frac{\sin x}x+\ln x}=\frac{\ln\frac{\sin mx}{mx}+\ln x+\ln m}{\ln \frac{\sin x}x+\ln x}$$

then recall that

- $\frac{\sin mx}{mx} \to 1 \implies \ln\frac{\sin mx}{mx}\to 0$
- $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1 \implies \ln\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 0$

and then the limit is determined by the $\ln x$ terms.

Answer (score 2):

You want $1+\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln\frac{\sin mx}{\sin x}}{\ln\sin x}$. The numerator $\to \ln m$, the denominator $\to -\infty$. The result is therefore $1+0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

According to L^Hopital's rule we have $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln\sin mx}{\ln \sin x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{m\cos mx}{\cos x}{\sin x\over \sin mx}=1$$